# How to choose a proper buffer length for TcpClient?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Some examples I see a buffer length of 1024, others 2048, and some 4096.

How should one set such a value or decide on which to use?

Still learning about how exactly TcpClient works and I'm a bit confused in this regard.

Is there any benefit towards having a smaller or larger buffer length?

Answer (score 2):

Your buffer size depends on how much data you want to read or write at a given time.  So you set it to whatever your read or write size is.

Comment: So I shouldn't always use the same buffer size? Should it basically always be the size of how much data I am transmitting? For example, if I only have to transmit 4 bytes the size should be 4 for that instance and if I later need to transmit 8 make it 8?

Comment: Well, you could do that.  But, that is likely to churn up a lot of heap space.  It is probably better to reuse the same buffer, so you would want to make it as large as you might possibly need.  Remember, this is just per request.